# Import own data like MNIST or CIFAR10 load_data()

Tags: python, arrays, deep-learning

I have a folder with images (around 4500), I want to load them to feed a GAN that I already wrote, so I want to load my images in X_train like the CIFAR10 or MNIST load_data() function.

I've tried this function (all the data in folder is with label 0..) :

```
def get_data(path):
    all_images_as_array=[]
    label=[]
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        label.append(0)
        img=Image.open(path + filename)
        np_array = np.asarray(img)
        l,b,c = np_array.shape
        np_array = np_array.reshape(l*b*c,)
        all_images_as_array.append(np_array)
    return np.array(all_images_as_array), np.array(label)
```

but it return a array of shape:

```
(4364, 3072)
```

EDIT : I think 3072 is because images are 32*32*3 ...

and I want a array of the same shape as returned by MNIST or CIFAR10 load_data() :

```
(NumberOfImages, 32, 32, 3)
```

How can I change my function ?

Thanks

PS : I'm sorry, I'm beginner in Python so I dont understand well the mechanics above these systems : thanks for any help

Comment: remove `np_array = np_array.reshape(l*b*c,)`

Comment: wow thanks, absolutely apologize for that obvious mistake...maybe the end oh the day ...and week

Comment: ok will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `np.array` was shape `l,b,c` at this point `np_array = np.asarray(img)`
you then reshaped it with `np_array = np_array.reshape(l*b*c,)` which is what you didn't want. Just remove those 2 lines

Also since you label is always 0 no need to have it append in the loop, just return it.

```
def get_data(path):
    all_images_as_array=[]
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        img=Image.open(path + filename)
        np_array = np.asarray(img)
        all_images_as_array.append(np_array)

    all_images = np.array(all_images_as_array)
    return all_images, np.zeros_like(all_images)
```